# Gulp - Cannot find module './gulp/uild.js'

Tags: javascript, npm, gulp

When I compile with gulp i got an error like below.

Operating system Windows 10

> gulp serve

```
module.js:471
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './gulp/uild.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at D:\test\gulpfile.js:13:3
    at Array.map (native)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\test\gulpfile.js:12:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could we see your *gulpfile.js* file?

Inside, it must have something like this:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
  // place code for your default task here
});
```

Another option is to run *npm install*.

Taken from the [docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

> **npm install (in package directory, no arguments):**
>
> Install the dependencies in the local node_modules folder.
>
> In global mode (ie, with -g or --global appended to the command), it installs the current package context (ie, the current working directory) as a global package.
> By default, ***npm install*** will install all modules listed as dependencies in ***package.json***.
> With the --production flag (or when the NODE_ENV environment variable is set to production), npm will not install modules listed in devDependencies.

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you are missing `b` letter in `build` in `./gulp/uild.js` in `D:\test\gulpfile.js` at line `13`